# Entering the https version of my site redirects to thank you Page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

When I enter the https version of my site. It redirects me to my Thank You Page.

my website is gobusinessplans.com. I do however have a popup wherein if a user completes the form they will redirect to the thank you page.

What seems to be the problem?

This is the contents of my htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/plain "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

# START - Disable server signature #
ServerSignature Off
# END - Disable server signature #
```

Comment: Could you show your `.htaccess` contents, since on your https you are doing a `301` redirect to thank you page.

Comment: Is there a possibility you made changes to the apache config and you have a redirect on HTTPS? could you please share with us your apache site configuration as well?

Comment: I forgot to tell that I got https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/ for my wordpress site. It only started when I set it to the most aggressive.

Comment: I made backups before I installed the plugin, and I reverted the site already including the database and it still redirects

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have to delete the plugin and wait for some time for the redirect to be gone.